# How to make a specific merge

Tags: php, laravel, array-merge

I'm trying to merge two arrays in one result

```
$array1 =["pack_id","pack_name","cash"];

$array2 =["pack_id","pack_name","inactifs","actifs","total"];
```

My code below :

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($cashByPacks); $i++) {
            $result[$i] = array('pack_id' => $cashByPacks[$i]->pack_id, 'pack_name' => $cashByPacks[$i]->pack_name, 'effectif' => 0, 'cash' => $cashByPacks[$i]->cash ?? 0, 'actif' => 0, 'inactif' => 0, 'percent' => 0);

            for ($j = 0; $j < count($query); $j++) {
                if (array_search($query[$j]->pack_id, $result[$i])) {
                    $result[$j] = array('pack_id' => $query[$j]->pack_id, 'pack_name' => $query[$j]->pack_name, 'effectif' => $query[$j]->total, 'actif' => $query[$j]->actifs, 'inactif' => $query[$j]->inactifs, 'cash' => $cashByPacks[$i]->cash ?? 0, 'percent' => ($cashByPacks[$i]->cash == 0) ? 0 : round(($cashByPacks[$i]->cash / $totalcash) * 100, 2));
                }

            }
        }
        return $result;
```

I expect the output will be one array that contain:

```
["pack_id","pack_name","cash","actifs","inactifs","totale"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_merge and array_diff.
Array_diff finds what is different between the two arrays and array_merge merges the two.

```
$arr1 = ["pack_id","pack_name","cash"];

$arr2 =["pack_id","pack_name","inactifs","actifs","total"];

$res = array_merge($arr1, array_diff($arr2, $arr1));

var_dump($res);
```

Or use array_merge and array_unique.
Array_merge will merge the two arrays and create duplicates, array_unique will remove the duplicates.

```
$arr1 = ["pack_id","pack_name","cash"];

$arr2 =["pack_id","pack_name","inactifs","actifs","total"];

$res = array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr2));

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: thx dude but it's not working im getting this error ```Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string```

Comment: In that case your arrays doesn't look like what you say in question

Comment: exactly in this format  ```0 => {#1086 ▼
    +"pack_id": "1"
    +"pack_name": "Cadeau"
    +"cash": "0"
  }  1 => {#1101 ▼
    +"pack_id": "2"
    +"pack_name": "Concours eXpress"
    +"cash": "0"
  }```

Comment: i'ts a php code (Laravel) , the two arrays (Query builder result) that's why